# Are there any way to set a default size for Chrome window?

Tags: google-chrome, resize

Are there any way to set a default size for Chrome window?
I usually have many Chrome tabs opened and resized them to fit the screen, and the next time I open Chrome, the newly opened window still has the same size as the last time. Are there any way to make Chrome opens up in the default size window every time?